# Angular-meteor Can I update to Angular 4?

Tags: angular-meteor

Now that Angular 4 has come out, can I update the version of Angular being used so I can learn and use the new features? If so how do I do that?

Update: I tried updating it through npm and started getting an error in the console and none of the new Angular 4 features worked afterward. Has anyone got it to work? Maybe I'll just learn Blaze and later change it to Angular when angular-meteor is updated to work with the current version of angular.

I might have updated it wrong. I just updated the angular through npm and made sure everything else was updated as well.

Comment: Following. this can't find any solution of that. I think you can update the question tag. to meteor and angular so that this reach more people.